# Using face detection feature of react-native-camera

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-camera

I'm trying to do real-time face detection in my React Native app using the `react-native-camera` module. I have the base module (just the camera) working fine in the app, and importing the `FaceDetector` class works fine, but when I add an `onFacesDetected` attribute to my camera component, it breaks the app. The entire app freezes when this happens, and I have to rebuild it. I don't get a formal error message anywhere, but Xcode says:

`Thread 19: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10ac70000)`

Anyone know what's going on?

BTW: This only happens on device. It works fine in the iOS Simulator

Answer (score 2):

Face Detection is optional on iOS. If you want them, you are going to need to install Google Mobile Vision frameworks in your project, as mentioned in the below link.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera#face-detection-or-text-recognition-steps

Answer (score 0):

Face detector functionality is not included by default with react-native-camera.
GMV (Google Mobile Vision) is used for Face detection by the iOS RNCamera so you need to install those dependencies in order for it to work.

I use cocoa pods to install these dependencies.

Here is my podfile:

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Your app name' do

pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'

pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'

pod 'GoogleMobileVision/Detector'

pod 'GoogleMobileVision/MVDataOutput'

pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
  'FaceDetector'
]

end